# WPF Tab header should show menu on mouse hover

Tags: wpf, stack-overflow, mouseover

I want to show menu or context menu when I mouse over on Tab Header. Actually I have done so on MouseUp event (means Click) but I am having difficulty when I mouse over on tab header.

Codebehind is as follows:

```
private void tabItem_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenu cm = (sender as TabItem).ContextMenu;
       cm.PlacementTarget = sender as TabItem;
       cm.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
        cm.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

if I use MouseMove or MouseEnter event then it throws exception:

> `"An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in PresentationCore.dll" on cm.IsOpen= true; line.`

Comment: Perhaps the `IsOpen` property calls `tabItem_MouseUp` again? Leading to a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: yes i know that is the reason but how we can fix that ?